# Which website should I use to choose restaurants in Australia?

Tags: online-resources, australia, restaurants

Which websites do people use in Australia for the purpose of chosing local restaurants?

Comment: I think this is way too opinion-based. How would you define popularity? It depends on personal taste.

Comment: I'm not looking for a "universal answer", I just wanted to find out what people usually use. I took a look at Yelp, and I was left with the feeling that it's not as popular in Australia as in the US. That's why I asked about other options. If I delete "most popular" from the question, will it stop being opinion-based?

Comment: Google or TripAdvisor generally does the trick.

Comment: I guess these questions are primarily opinion based unless there is usage data but it would be nice if there was a canonical list.. it took me a while to find “open rice” for HK, for example.

Comment: This is a perfect question and it's silly it was closed.  Now, back to 100 absurd visa questions.

Comment: I have a suspicion that the most commonly used sites will differ between countries, which makes it worthwhile asking, and travel related.

Comment: @Fattie: Would this not fall under the category of "eliciting list-style answers, suggestions or recommendations on a topic or place" which is specifically off topic?

Comment: "How would you define popularity?"  ........... ?   Popularity ("most used") is completely quantifiable.  No opinion involved.

Comment: I wonder what the reason for two downvotes is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 2019, **Zomato** (formerly Urbanspoon) https://www.zomato.com is the most popular Australian review site by a mile.  It covers everything from kebab joints to frou-frou five stars.

The **Good Food Guide** https://www.goodfood.com.au/ is also worth a mention: it focuses more on high-end restaurants, but unlike the free-for-all of Zomato, the reviews are written by professionals.

Food delivery services like Menulog, Deliveroo and Uber Eats are handy if you want to get an idea of what's on the menu at most restaurants.

Personally, I use **Google Maps** a lot because I find the UI far superior to the convoluted mess of Zomato, but there are generally fewer reviews, photos, menus etc.